# How to create instances of type declarations?

Tags: c#, types, instance

I want to store a class declaration in a struct and later instantiate new objects from that class but I'm running into a few obstacles. I know how to do this in a few other languages but in C# I didn't have any success yet.

```
abstract class Command
{
    // Base class for all concrete command classes.
}

class FooCommand : Command
{
}

class ListCommand : Command
{
}
```

Now I want to have a struct that stores some data and a Command subclass class ref:

```
struct CommandVO
{
    string trigger;
    string category;
    Type commandClass;
}
```

Somewhere else later on I want to fetch the VO structs from a dictionary and create concrete command objects:

```
var commandMap = new Dictionary<string, CommandVO?>(100);
commandMap.Add("foo", new CommandVO
{
    trigger = "foo", category = "foo commands", commandClass = FooCommand
});
commandMap.Add("list", new CommandVO
{
    trigger = "list", category = "list commands", commandClass = ListCommand
});
```

...

```
var commandVO = commandMap["foo"];
if (commandVO != null)
{
    var commandClass = commandVO.Value.commandClass;
    // How to instantiate the commandClass to a FooCommand object here?
}
```

I've checked this [page](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/15938/creating-an-instance-of-a-type) for methods on how to instantiate types but since `Type` doesn't represent any concrete class I wonder how do I get `commandClass` to instantiate to a proper object of its type? And is it correct in this case to store class declarations as `Type` in the struct or is there a better approach?

Comment: use Activator.CreateInstance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: does this even compile to you? You have to write `typeof(FooCommand)`

Comment: @PawełAudionysos part of this is pseudocode that I wrote from my head. I think I found what I need: `var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(commandClass);
var obj = instance as Command;
if (obj != null) var command = obj;`

Comment: Add it as an answer :) Not everyone who stumbles on this will read the comments.

Comment: It's common to use a `Func<Command>` instead of a Type here. That avoids the overhead of Activator.CreateInstance, and also lets you have commands which don't have parameterless constructors. `Func<Command> Factory` then `Factory = () => new FooCommand() ` to assign it, and `.Factory() ` to call it and create your new `Command`

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap type with `typeof()`:

```
var commandMap = new Dictionary<string, CommandVO?>(100);
commandMap.Add("foo", new CommandVO {
    trigger = "foo", category = "foo commands", commandClass = typeof(FooCommand)
});
```

You can write extension method like this:

```
internal static class CommandHelper {

    internal static Command createCommand(this Dictionary<string, CommandVO?> d, string name) {
        if (!d.ContainsKey(name)) return null;
        return Activator.CreateInstance(d[name]?.commandClass) as Command;
    }

}
```

Than you can get your `Cammand` instance:

```
var instance = commandMap.createCommand("foo");
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints about using typeof!